# Unable to connect to AWS EC2 instance public IPv4 using http tcp/80

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, aws-ec2, eclipse

Referring to an instructional book,
I am setting up an EC2 instance on AWS using an IAM role.

However, when I try to access the URL using the EC2 instance's public IP address, I am unable to establish a connection.

`URL: http://(public IPv4 address)/aws-sample`

I followed these steps:

1. Configured IAM Roles
2. Created a Security Group
3. Created the EC2 Instance
4. My process for creating the EC2 instance:

   1. Created a key pair
   2. Entered user data
   3. Started the instance

Here's the error message I encountered:

> This site can't be reached. The IP address -.-.-.- took too long to respond. Try checking the connection.

I've already tried:

1.Checking the connection

If you have any insights or solutions, please share. Thank you.

> [Environment:]
>
> Windows 11 
> Apache 2.4.56 
> Tomcat 17.0.8.7.1 
> Eclipse 2022-09 
> Platform: Likely Amazon Linux 
> Platform Details: Linux/UNIX

I've already tried:

1. Checking the connection - But it was no use.
2. I looked at this article(but the problem seems still remain) Checking my setting of "Security Group" and "Port connection"

Should an AWS EC2 instance connect using only IPv4 Public IP?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143943/should-an-aws-ec2-instance-connect-using-only-ipv4-public-ip

Comment: If you have the nmap utility aim that at your ip address: nmap <your public ip address>. It'll scan a bunch of system ports and tell you what it sees open.